# Problems with ListPolarPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the data that I got from measuring the angular dependency of the radiation intensity of a microwave emitter.

My data:

```
data = {
  {-90, 0}, {-85, 0.15}, {-80, 0}, {-75, 0}, {-70, 0}, {-65, 0}, {-60, 0.2}, 
  {-55, 0}, {-50, 0}, {-45, 0.275}, {-40, 0.225}, {-35, 0.425}, {-30, 0.55}, 
  {-25, 0.65}, {-20, 0.75}, {-15, 0.85}, {-10, 0.9}, {-5, 1}, {0, 0.975}, 
  {5, 0.9}, {10, 0.8}, {15, 0.725}, {20, 0.635}, {25, 0.475}, {30, 0.425}, 
  {35, 0.2}, {40, 0.15}, {45, 0.175}, {50, 0.15}, {55, 0}, {60, 0}, {65, 0}, 
  {70, 0}, {75, 0}, {80, 0}, {85, 0}, {90, 0}
}
```

[image]

As you can see my data ranges from -90 to 90 degree in 5 degree steps.

Now, if I try to plot this using `ListPolarPlot[]` it gets kind of messy:

```
ListPolarPlot[data, 
  PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

It should look somewhat like this:

[image]

What do I have to do to get a proper polar plot?

Comment: @m_goldberg Careful! you would be messing with the radiation intensity

Comment: @Ivan. You are right. I have retracted my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the angles in radians in your data:

```
data2 = {#[[1]]*Pi/180, #[[2]]} & /@ data;
```

Or

```
data2 = {#[[1]] Degree, #[[2]]} & /@ data;
```

Then plot

```
ListPolarPlot[data2, PolarAxes -> True,
   PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, Joined -> True, PolarGridLines -> True]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

To show only part of the circle, play around with the `PlotRange` option.
And to show negative angles, specify them in `PolarThicks` option.

```
 ListPolarPlot[data2, PolarAxes -> True, Joined -> True, PolarGridLines -> True,
    PolarTicks -> {Table[i, {i, -90, 90, 15}] Degree, Automatic},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: BTW: `Degree` is built-in…

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way of only showing 90 to 270 degrees? And can I change 0,359,358,...,270 degree to 0,-1,-2,...-90 degree?

Comment: @kaos I updated my post. Check it out.

Comment: Cool. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

You might try this simple way to convert your data.

```
data[[All, 1]] = data[[All, 1]] Degree
ListPolarPlot[data, 
  PolarAxes -> True, PolarGridLines -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
  Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: `data[[All, 1]] *= Degree` will work, too.